# Comparison between randomised search and grid search for hyper-parameter estimation

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I want to do hyperparameter tuning and for that, I want to use RandomizedSearchCV or GridSearchCV. I tried to run both of the methods for Random Forest classifier.

I found that Grid search will search on all the possible combination of my parameter grid, but the randomized search is searching only 10 possible combinations. Assuming that it is taking any 10 random set of parameters, it might give me false best parameters. On the other hand, if I use GridSearch method, then it gives me large runtime. Now, I am confused between this two methods. Which should I use? Or can I do some changes that will give me best parameters in acceptable runtime?

Comment: please explain your use case.if u need all combinations then what is the point in using randomized search?

Comment: @JoeSebin Sorry if I was not clear. But I want to get best parameters. But my problem is randomized search might not give me that and Grid search is taking a lot of time. So, Is there anything I can do to get best parameters within the acceptable time.

Comment: I suggest you try reading about the [No Free Lunch Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperparameter tuning scheme depends on your application. As for Grid Search and Randomised Search:

- Grid Search works good when you have a small number of hyperparameters, and when each hyperparameter has about the same magnitude of impact on validation score
- Randomised Search is a better option when magnitudes of influence are imbalanced, which is more likely to happen as your number of parameters is growing

*Source: deeplearning.ai course on hparam tuning [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/deep-neural-network/lecture/dknSn/tuning-process)*

Other schemes for tuning include

- Coarse to Fine coarse : Sample with Grid Search coarsely the hyperparameter space at first, and concentrate samples where validation score is higher
- Bayesian Optimization with gaussian processes: [here](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization)